# GitHub CI error parsing HTTP 404 response body when pushing the image

Tags: docker, gradle, github, github-ci

Coming from this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58920140/10420300)

I am using GitHub Actions for Gradle project with this given steps:

```
name: Java CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up JDK 13
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 13

      - run: ./gradlew bootJar

      - name: Login to Github regestry
        run: docker login docker.pkg.github.com -u xxxxx -p xxxxx

      - name: Build the Docker image
        run: docker build . -t docker.pkg.github.com/sulimanlab/realtime-chat/realtimechat-snapshot-0.$GITHUB_REF


      - name: Push the image to github
        run: docker push docker.pkg.github.com/sulimanlab/realtime-chat/realtimechat-snapshot-0.$GITHUB_REF
```

**At the last step** I get this error:

> The push refers to repository
>   [docker.pkg.github.com/sulimanlab/realtime-chat/realtimechat-snapshot-0.refs/heads/master]
>
> 3aad04996f8f: Preparing
>
> 77cae8ab23bf: Preparing
>
> error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character 'p' after top-level value:
>   "404 page not found\n"

Comment: This seems like an issue with docker, not github actions. See this [issue](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1697)

Comment: I solved it actually, many thanks man 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58938666/10420300

Comment: Nice one. I was just about to post something I read about [github packages](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/configuring-docker-for-use-with-github-packages#publishing-a-package). It says the way to push is to use the syntax `docker push docker.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY/IMAGE_NAME:VERSION`, then below that it says, _**Note**: You must push your image using `IMAGE_NAME:VERSION` and not using `IMAGE_NAME:SHA`_. If this works for you, I guess it works then which is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually I was using the wrong environment variable to tag my images.

I used **$GITHUB_REF** what I should use **$GITHUB_SHA**